# How to make JasperReports ask for a parameter upon program load?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, ireport

I have create a program that loads JR report. I placed a parameter on the report so that whenever the report loads, it will ask for a value. It worked fine when I pass a parameter on my java program

```
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("VoucherNo", oclsJVHeader.getJournalVoucherNo()); 
...
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);
```

but when I try to load it without a paramater,

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn);
```

it says "The document has no pages". I was thinking that since i made the parameter use a prompt whenever my code do not pass a parameter, it will ask for a prompt when i load it.

```
<parameter name="VoucherNo" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="true">
```

So my question is, how do I make the report prompt for a value whenever I do not pass a parameter? Do I need to change my java code for this?

Btw here is my code for loading the report:

```
 FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(reportPath+reportFile);
 JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(fs);
 JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
 JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters,  conn); //could be null or parameters
 JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Journal Voucher");
 jframe.getContentPane().add(new JRViewer(jasperPrint));
 jframe.pack();
 jframe.setExtendedState(javax.swing.JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
 jframe.setVisible(true);
```

I am using *iReport* and *NetBeans* for my project.

Comment: You question in unclear. You said that you have already gui for setting parameters (`I placed a parameter on the report so that whenever the report loads, it will ask for a value`). But after that you are asking about how to set parameter (`So my question is, how do I make the report prompt for a value whenever I do not pass a parameter?`). What do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, the `isForPrompting` parameter is only used by iReport and JasperServer (and could be used by any other generic app generating reports).

Anyway, how is JasperReport supposed to know how it should ask the parameter value? And if your application was a webapp? Or a command-line app? Jasper Reports generates reports. You should provide the necessary GUI.

Comment: how is JasperReport supposed to know how it should ask the parameter value? - that I really dont know. I am new to jasper report. Do you have any idea how? please help. I created a swing application for this. I created a JFrame as seen on the code to print the report

Comment: I believe it was a rhetorical question. You could interpret it to mean, "It's clearly impossible for JasperReports to know how to prompt for a parameter, since it cannot know the context in which it is running." You need to write code in your Swing app to prompt the user for parameters.